# How many relationship levels i can go Formula field

Tags: formula-field

What is the updated relationship levels I can achieve through formula fields?
I did not find any proper documentation.

Comment: You can have up to 7 levels.

Comment: @kevan - i think 7 level limit is for the nested map and not for the formula.

Comment: Has changed since, up to 10 relationships (Spring 18)

Answer (score 6):

You can reference fields from objects that are up to 10 relationships away

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=0) is Help article from salesforce.

Comment: Thanks, And in SOQL query for child to parent, we can specify maximum 5 levels?